# What could cause Blender to crash and freeze a PC only during low-poly scenes using the cycles engine?

Tags: rendering

I noticed today that after building a scene with only 388 vertices that Blender tended to crash while also causing my computer to freeze. However, it did not crash when rendering a more complex scene with over 92,382 vertices. The scene with 92,382 vertices also has a mantaflow smoke simulation active, so I am not understanding why Blender is struggling with a more basic scene. Both were rendered with the cycles engine using the GPU and tiles sizes of 256 by 256. The **Blender Version is 3.0.1**. The **specs of my computer** are as follows:

CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 3600x 6-core processor 3.80 GHz

GPU: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2060

Baseboard Product: ROG STRIX B45-F GAMING

Installed Ram: 16 GB

OS: Windows 10 Home

Statistics of the High-Poly Scene:

Objects: 1/140 objects
Vertices: 92,382
Edges: 177,456
Faces 85,879
Triangles: 176,881
Resolution: 500 by 500 pixels

Statistics of the Low-Poly Scene:

Objects: 1/5
Vertices: 388
Edges: 512
Faces: 157
Triangles: 434
Resolution 96 by 32 pixels

Unfortunately there is no crash log because my entire computer freezes when I attempt to render. I tried closing any other apps and rendering the scene, but that didn't work. I got rid of any materials that were not being used and rendering it, but that didn't work. Finally, I tried making a new project file and bringing the objects in and rendering it, but that didn't work. If anyone can shed light on this issue that would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Is the crash tied to the specific blend file or the model itself? Have you tried rendering the same model in a new project?

Comment: @Jakemoyo definitely the model itself, I tried to import the model into a new project and it crashed.